# How to check the value within json is string or array in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I have a array Json like this in node js.

JSON 1

```
var json1= {
  bookmarkname: 'My Health Circles',
  bookmarkurl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  bookmark_system_category: [ '22', '1' ]
}
```

JSON 2

```
var json2 = {
  bookmarkname: 'My Health Circles',
  bookmarkurl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  bookmark_system_category:'22'
}
```

I tried :

```
var length1=json1.bookmark_system_category.length;

var length1=json2.bookmark_system_category.length;
```

Expected output :

```
l1=2;
l2=1;
```

Comment: FYI that's an object, not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `length` is property of `string` as well as `array`

In your second case, it is counting length of the `string` which is **2**

May be you will need a condition:

```js
var json1 = {
  bookmarkname: 'My Health Circles',
  bookmarkurl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  bookmark_system_category: ['22', '1']
};
var json2 = {
  bookmarkname: 'My Health Circles',
  bookmarkurl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  bookmark_system_category: '22'
};

var getLength = function(input) {
  if (typeof input === 'string') {
    return 'Is String';
  } else {
    return input.length;
  }
}

var length1 = getLength(json1.bookmark_system_category);
var length2 = getLength(json2.bookmark_system_category);
alert(length1);
alert(length2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.isArray`:

```
Array.isArray(json1.bookmark_system_category); // true
```

but this would return `false` for everything that isn't an array - strings, objects, `null`.

Here's a nifty function that will return the type of an object (in lowercase) that you can test against:

```
function toType(x) {
  return ({}).toString.call(x).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

toType({}) // object
toType([]) // array
toType(null) // null
toType(0) // number
toType('bob') // string
```

So:

```
toType(json1.bookmark_system_category) // array
toType(json2.bookmark_system_category) // string
```